# How to get a single value from a spark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe as shown below:

```
Col1  Col2
1.2   9.8
3.4   8.8
```

I would like retrieve value Col2[2] of  single value from a column

How would I achieve this in spark

I tried below code:

```
t = df[0].__getitem__("Col2")

Column<b'Col1[Col2]'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use **`.rdd`** to convert df to rdd then by using **`lambda function`** we can get only **`Col2`** from the row object!

```
df.show()
+----+----+
|Col1|Col2|
+----+----+
| 1.2| 9.8|
| 3.4| 8.8|
+----+----+

#to get col2 second row
df.collect()[1][1]
#8.8

#to get col2
df.rdd.map(lambda x:x.Col2).collect()
[9.8, 8.8]
```